# Unable to install XLWings add-in into Excel?

Tags: python, excel, vba, xlwings

I want to try this add-in for Excel. To use the add-in there must be an XLAM file. However, there is no link to one on the website (xlwings.org). Even using pip to 'download/install' xlwings, it doesn't include the command client that the documentation claims it does. As such, there is no possible way on the user end to get xlwings that we can determine.

Using command prompt doesn't work. We have all the files, however. I see the directory, including the quick start macro. But command prompt will not execute xlwings or any other command, thus rendering the module unable to be used.

[The documentation states:](http://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/addin.html#xlwings-addin) *"To install the add-in, it’s easiest to use the command line client: xlwings addin install."* Typing this into command prompt doesn't work, even when I changed my path environment variables to point towards the XLWings folder (which contains the quickstart file they mention).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Great question. I also had a great deal of trouble myself when trying to install this add-in, as it is near impossible to locate on their site. However, I eventually found the link to download it here:
https://github.com/ZoomerAnalytics/xlwings/releases/download/v0.11.4/xlwings.xlam

Comment: Wow thanks so much. I literally couldn't find it no matter what I tried xD this was very helpful thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

I'll add to this for anyone else who comes along.  I also had a lot of trouble with the add-in.

If it is an option for you, installing [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/) will get you xlwings and a pile of other packages along with Anaconda Navigator which give you Spyder IDE and Jupyter Notebooks if those are of any interest.  xlwings command line gets installed as well.  I first uninstalled previous versions of Python to eliminate confusion.

Now pick a work directory and start a project with

```
xlwings quickstart AProjectName
```

You will get a folder AProjectName with a starter xlsm and py files of the same name.  Open AProjectName.xlsm and open VBA Explorer.  Export the xlwings module.  Now you will have xlwings.bas that you can import into any workbook and you don't need an add-in.  This should be helpful when sharing your workbook with others.  They will need to install Anaconda or Python + xlwings, but no need for an add-in.