# "FileNotFoundError" for xlwings add installation

Tags: windows, conda, excel-addins, xlwings, filenotfounderror

I try to install xlwings addin in a conda cmd, but getting this error:

```
>xlwings addin install
xlwings version: 0.29.1
FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory')
```

I downloaded https://github.com/ZoomerAnalytics/xlwings/releases/download/v0.11.4/xlwings.xlam as suggested here: [Unable to install XLWings add-in into Excel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45757157/unable-to-install-xlwings-add-in-into-excel), and saved it to C:\Users$user, but it gives me the error, what am I missing here?

Comment: The linked xlam file is an old version, only has a size of 69,479 bytes. You should use the latest or at least the same release as the Xlwings version you are using. The file is included with the install when installing using Pip and will be located in `<package>\xlwings-0.31.0\xlwings\addin` , the latest size is 271 285 bytes. I don't know what you get using Conda as I don't use it.   I assume that `xlwings addin install` will look for the file in the location mentioned so if Conda is different it may not work.

Comment: As the xlwings command states it will copy the xlam file to the Users XLSTART folder, so you can do this manually. If you don't have the latest xlam file you can download the tar from [pypi.org](https://pypi.org/project/xlwings/) extract the file and place it in `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Excel\XLSTART`